# ERROR: function regexp_like(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this `SQL` query that I'm writing using `Postgresql`.

```
select * from cdr_data 
  where REGEXP_LIKE(identifiant,'^73')
    and REGEXP_REPLACE(callednumber,'^256','') ~ '^73'
```

It gives me following error:

```
[Err] ERROR:  function regexp_like(character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 2: and  regexp_like(identifiant,'^73')
```

I have tried replace with `REGEXP_LIKE` with `LIKE` and `REGEXP_MATCHES` but they don't work.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `regexp_like` is an Oracle function. Use postgresql documentation to find what functions are available.

Comment: Here's a starting point in the Postgresql docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: @roykasa whever you get that error `function ..... unknown) does not exist` that means two things (usually) 1. it's a function alien to the language you are using 2. you have typed a built in function wrongly ;) and third possibly (to put explicitly) you have written a UDF and something wrong with it..

Comment: seriously, you post a question in which you have already the answer. Indeed, you already use ~ operator in line with `regexp_replace`  function ! And ~ operator is not an Oracle operator.

Comment: Starting in Postgres 15, this actually works – https://pgpedia.info/r/regexp_like.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The PostgreSQL equivalent of `regexp_like(identifiant,'^73')` is `identifiant ~ '^73'`

Comment: `regexp_matches()` is another alternative.

Comment: `regexp_matches()` returns substrings, not booleans.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `SIMILAR TO` operator?

Some snippets from PostgreSQL documentation:

```
a. `select 'abc' SIMILAR TO '(a|d)%';`
b. `select 'def' SIMILAR TO '(a|b|c)%';`
```

Statement a returns `t` (true) as 'abc' starts with 'a' or 'd'.
Statement b returns `f` (false) as 'def' doesn't start with either 'a' or 'b' or 'c'.

Comment: `SIMILAR TO` provides the same results as `~`.

See section "Why are regular expressions (~) always faster than SIMILAR TO?" in this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/171262

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use one of following functions

```
value_or_colum_name ~ '<regex-expression>'
value_or_colum_name SIMILAR TO '<regex-expression>'
TEXTREGEXEQ(value_or_colum_name,'<regex-expression>')
```

all these 3 possibilities are totaly equivalent.

The `REGEXP_LIKE` fonction doesn't exists on SqlPostGreSQL.
But `REGEXP_MATCHES` and `REGEXP_REPLACE` exist.

Here is a command using `~` and `REGEXP_REPLACE` that I used to check if my Regular Expresion work correctly before starting an SQL `UPDATE`.

```
SELECT communication
      ,REGEXP_REPLACE
         (communication
         ,'(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{5})'
         ,'***\1/\2/\3***'
         ) as ref 
  FROM mouvements 
  WHERE communication ~ '^\d{12}$'
```

this give following results

```
comm            ref
------------------------------------
303000167868    ***303/0001/67868***
121231357408    ***121/2313/57408***
321000204456    ***321/0002/04456***
```

and the final UPDATE command is

```
UPDATE mouvements
  SET communication = NULL
     ,Ref_Structured = REGEXP_REPLACE(communication,'(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{5})','***\1/\2/\3***')
  WHERE communication ~ '^\d{12}$'
```

another SQL `UPDATE` command that split a column is 2

```
UPDATE mouvements
  SET nom = REGEXP_REPLACE(nom,'^(.*)(REFERENCE DONNEUR D''ORDRE : )(.*)','\1')
     ,RefDonneur = REGEXP_REPLACE(nom,'^.*(REFERENCE DONNEUR D''ORDRE : )(.*)','\2')
  where nom ~ 'REFERENCE DONNEUR D''ORDRE :'
```